# How to save child properties?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Breeze & Angular & MV*

I get an invoice object and expand it's necessary properties: Customer, Details, etc.

To access detail properties is easy, invoice.detail[n].property. And saving changes to existing properties (1 - n) is also easy.  In my UI, I simply loop through my object vm.invoice.details to get & display all existing details, bind them to inputs, edit at will, call saveChanges(), done!

(keep in mind, in this UI, I need to complete the following too....)

Now, I have blank inputs for a new detail I need to insert.

However, I need to insert a new detail into the existing array of invoice details.

For example:  invoice #5 has 3 details (detail[0], detail[1], detail[2]). I need to insert into this existing invoice, detail[3], and call saveChanges()

I've tried to call the manger.createEntity('invoice') but it complains about FK constraints.  I know you can pass values as a second argument in createEntity('obj', newvalues)...but is that the correct and only method?

Seems like this should all be much easier but, well, I am at a loss so, please help where you can.  TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [DocCode sample](http://www.getbreezenow.com/samples/doccode) which has tests for all kinds of scenarios including this one.

Perhaps the following provides the insight you're looking for:

```
function addNewDetail() {
    var newDetail = manager.createEntity('Detail', {
        invoice: vm.currentInvoice,
        ... other initial values
     });

    // the newDetail will show up automatically if the view is bound to vm.details
}
```

Notice that I'm initializing the parent `invoice` navigation property. Alternatively, I could just set the `Detail` entity's FK property inside the initializer:

```
...
invoiceId: vm.currentInvoice.id,
...
```

Either way, Breeze will add the new detail to the `details` collection of the `currentInvoice`.

Your question spoke in terms of ***inserting*** the new `Detail`. There is no need to insert the new `Detail` manually and you can't manage the sort order of the `vm.currentInvoice.details` property any way.

Breeze has **no notion of sort order** for collection navigation properties.

If you need to display the details in a particular order you could add a sorting filter to your angular binding to `vm.currentInvoice.details`.

Comment: thank you for the excellent reply!
Here's how I ended up accomplishing it:
In my **controller** I call a function that looks like this 
`var d = dataservice.createNewDetail(vm.invoice);
            d.SeqNumber = (vm.invoice.InvoiceDetails.length + 1);
            vm.invoice.InvoiceDetails.push(d);`   
Then my dataservice function need be nothing more than 
`return manager.createEntity('InvoiceDetail')'
I originally approached it as you suggested, see my OP (_ I know you can pass values as a second argument in createEntity('obj', newvalues)...but is that the correct and only method?_)

Comment: can I accept you answer?  In fact, your suggestion (while different) begs a new question: which approach is _correct_? I guess it comes down to what works best in your MV* environment?  If you see a weakness or danger in my approach, please advise further.  Else we can call this one closed.  All the best!

Comment: There is a slight difference that is unimportant in your case. If you set the nav property, Breeze will ensure that both parent and child are in the same `EntityManager` (throws if they are not). Setting the FK id doesn't impose that test and will only connect the new child `Detail` to the parent `Invoice` if that invoice is present in the child's manager. Not an issue for you given that you have only one manager. Pick the approach that feels best to you.

Comment: Actually, I think creating the detail and then pushing it into the invoice's `InvoiceDetails` property is a third way that would also work IF the `Detail.InvoiceId` property is allowed to be null. I'm guessing that this is not allowed ... which means the `Detail.InvoiceId` property is initialized to `0` and maybe you're getting an error from that? Myself, I set the FK or the nav property in the initializer so there is never a moment's doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct EntityName, because sometimes creating entity is a not as simple as it seems.Before working with entities see

> http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/creating-entities

I will suggest you to look ur metadata file, go to last line of your file, you can see the field named "entitySet"

```
"entitySet":{"name":"Entity_Name","entityType":"Self.Entity_Name"}
```

check the entityName here i took as "Entity_Name" and then try to create the entity and use this name

```
  manger.createEntity('Entity_Name');
```

Comment: Yes.  Very good suggestion, thank you.  I have tested my entity correctness by hardcoding some initial values and using them as second param for createEntity.  This successfully inserted new values and confirmed that my entity is correctly named.